# Graph Data Science library not in Azure Neo4j VM

Tags: azure, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I have created a Neo4j VM Enterprise 4.0 on Azure.

On this VM I called call dbms.procedures. I saw that Graph Data Science (GDS) is not installed on this VM when this VM was created on Azure. Usually I work with Neo4j Desktop and I just had to click on install button.
With a Neo4j VM in Azure I don't know how to install GDS.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions for installing APOC are [here](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/installation/).